# Keep getting undefined when calling 2 dimensional array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, typeerror

So I'm currently making a bit of script that will take in a value between 0 and 3999 and pump out the roman numerals for the number.  For some reason when calling my 2 dimensional array, I wind up getting undefined

```
            function romanConverter() {
                var romanOutput;
                var enteredNum = prompt('What number would you like converted between 1 and 3999?');
                var romanNum = [
                    ['', 'M', 'MM', 'MMM'], // Thousands place
                    ['', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM'], // Hundreds place
                    ['', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC'], // These are for the tens place
                    ['', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX'] // Ones place 
                ];

                if (parseInt(enteredNum) > 3999) {
                    alert("I'm sorry that's not a valid entry");
                    enteredNum = prompt('What number would you like converted between 1 and 3999?');
                } else {
                    while (enteredNum.length < 4) {
                        enteredNum = '0' + enteredNum;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i <= enteredNum.length; i += 1) {
                        var currentNum = parseInt(enteredNum.charAt(i));
                        romanOutput += romanNum[i][currentNum];
                    }
                }
                document.write(romanOutput);
            }
            romanConverter();
```

I always get the `TypeError: romanNum[i] is undefined`  I'm really stuck and could use some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those sneaky little errors that always makes you bang your head against a wall for a while.

Try changing your final `for` loop to the following:

`for (var i = 0; i < enteredNum.length; i += 1) { // etc...`

You want strictly less than - not less than or equal to. Otherwise, you'll end up evaluating something like `"05".charAt(2);`

To prevent its output from being `undefined` followed by the converted roman numeral, you will also want to change the line that says

```
var romanOutput;
```

To

```
var romanOutput = "";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was incredibly helpful.